# Export spring desktop application as jar to be used as utility

Tags: java, spring

I have created a utility as a Spring maven java project. The code is for my organisation so I cannot paste it here. I am new to spring and hence I am confused as to how the current application will be using my project. My project is a simple Java class with dependencies injected as bean. Will the application use the name of this class to instantiate it's methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be open your pom.xml file and check this line, if war/ear/... set it to jar

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Then build your project again, your jar file is in /target